# Using ONE TO ONE Mapping with Spring Boot Rest API with MySQL database

Tags: spring-boot, api, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am trying to create a Nesting Custom Type in spring Boot Rest Api. I have created Book.java entity class

```java
package com.api.book.bootrestbook.entities;



import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Book_ID")
    private int id;
    
    private String title;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    private Author author;
 
}
```

Author.java

```java
package com.api.book.bootrestbook.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int authorId;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;
    private String language;

 
}
```

I am trying to map Book class author data member with Author class object.

This is my handler method which will be used to fill details coming in request in the database table.

```java
@PostMapping("/books") 
    public Book addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        
        this.bookServiceJPA.addBook(book);
        return book;
    }
```

This is my BookServiceJPA class -

```java
package com.api.book.bootrestbook.services;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sound.sampled.Line;

import com.api.book.bootrestbook.dao.BookRepository;
import com.api.book.bootrestbook.entities.Book;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BookServiceJPA {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

   

    // adding a book for post request, We have to use post method for this purpose
    public void addBook(Book b) {
        this.bookRepository.save(b);
        System.out.println("Book details saved");
        return;
    }

   
}
```

This is my BookRepository interface -

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Integer>{
    public Book findById(int id);
    
}
```

After running my application it is running and Tables are also created but When I am trying to give request
[image]

My code is showing this error in console -

```java
2021-04-13 00:16:47.581  INFO 9404 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-13 00:16:47.583  INFO 9404 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-13 00:16:47.591  INFO 9404 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms  
2021-04-13 00:16:48.032 ERROR 9404 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.api.book.bootrestbook.entities.Author; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.api.book.bootrestbook.entities.Author] with root cause      

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.api.book.bootrestbook.entities.Author
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:744) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:712) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final] 
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]    
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:427) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]     
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.api.book.bootrestbook.services.BookServiceJPA.addBook(BookServiceJPA.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.api.book.bootrestbook.controllers.BookController.addBook(BookController.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5] 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]   
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]        
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]       
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5] 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44] 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]  
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]       
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]    
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]    
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44] 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]     
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]  
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

I have no idea why it showing an error. I have copied all the steps from a video. His app is working but mine is showing an error.
Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the issue is with data you are passing to the Book and Author object are incorrect and wrong.

Example `Book_ID` does not map to Book pojo object actually it is `id` but for Author object you are passing the right one
`authorId`

As per my understanding Book is trying to save the Author object based on `authorId` of 6. But Author object with 6 is already presented in the database.

Basically this is because of `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` option

So the exact JSON to inserting a new record is

```
{
  "title": "Java",
  "author": {
    "firstName": "Mayank",
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "language": "English"
  }
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks, @GnanaJeyam, Your solution is working. And the output is {
    "id": 15,
    "title": "Java",
    "author": {
        "authorId": 16,
        "firstName": "Mayank",
        "lastName": null,
        "language": "English"
    }
}

Comment: As no value is passed for column lastName so its value is null.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s a good practice for One-To-One mapping to have it Bidirectional.
In your current setup, it is Unidirectional where the Book is the owning/parent entity. Should it be the Author?

If we will refactor your code, it should look similar to this (not tested).
**NOTE:** This assumes that the *Author* exists. Otherwise, we will use the `AuthorController, AuthorService, AuthorRepository`.

**AuthorEntity.java***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int authorId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = “last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = “language”)
    private String language;

    @OneToOne(
      mappedBy = “book”,
      orphanRemoval = true,
      cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE },
      fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Book book;
 }
```

**BookEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Book_ID")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = “title”)
    private String title;

    @JoinColumn(
      name = “author_id",
      referencedColumnName = "id",
      foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = “author_book_fk")
    )
    private Author author;
}
```

In your **BookController.java**, you must expect a **@RequestBody** the following: `title: ‘Data JPA’, author: 1`

In your **BookService.java**, you can do this.

```
public Book save(String bookTitle, Long authorId) {
    Author author = authorService.findById(authorId); // should be formatted to 1L, 2L, etc…
    
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle(bookTitle);
    book.setAuthor(author);

    bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

*I suggest you make use of DTO for handling data between controller<->service.